# Eager loading two tables with multiple Relationships in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have 3 models Tracktype, Tracks and Subgenres . The relationship is like this . A Tracktype has many tracks and a track can have many subgenres . but a track can only have one track type

I have already defined relationships like these

```
/**
 * Gets the tracks lists Associated with a track type
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\hasMany
 */
public function tracks()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Tracks', 'id', 'id');
}


/**
 * Get the Lists of tracks Associated with the Subgenre ID
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function tracks()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tracks', 'subgenre_track', 'subgenre_id', 'track_id');
}
```

I have tried something like this .

```
App\TrackType::with(['tracks.subgeneres' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('name', 'Trans');
}])->where('name', 'Single')->get();
```

But it's not returning the correct results

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [query] => select * from `tracktype` where `name` = ?
            [bindings] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Single
                )

        [time] => 0.55
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [query] => select * from `tracks` where `tracks`.`id` in (?)
        [bindings] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
            )

        [time] => 0.45
    )
)
```

My need is to get all tracks which are matching Tracktype of Single and Subgeneres matching Trans . I have both Tracktype table and Subgeneres table along with relevant pivot tables.

How to define these relationships?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by Changing method in Tracktype from hasMany to belongToMany . And That was it .Used the Same Query :)